# Sufficient condition for $\mathrm{ord}(a)$ divides exponent of finite abelian group?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

In Niederreiter and Winterhof, [Applied Number Theory](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319223209), Proposition 1.3.24 (p. 18) is:

> If $G$ is a finite abelian group of exponent $E$, then
> $\mathrm{ord}(a)$ divides $E$ for all $a \in G$.

They're using the multiplicative notation for the group operation.  The proof begins like this:

> We consider a fixed element $a \in G$. Let $p$ be any prime number.
> Then we can write $E=p^ef$ with integers $e\geq 0$ and $f\geq 1$
> satisfying $\gcd(p,f)=1$. It suffices to show that if $p^r$ divides
> $\mathrm{ord}(a)$ for some integer $r\geq 0$, then we must have $r\leq e$.

I don't understand why proving the last statement would be sufficient to prove the theorem.

I understand that the order of $a$ is the least $m$ s.t. $a^m = 1_G$, and that the exponent is the maximum of $\mathrm{ord}(a)$ for all $a \in G$.  We're trying to show that $\mathrm{ord}(a)$ divides $E=p^ef$ (where $f$ of course is a product of primes).  If $p^r$ divides $\mathrm{ord}(a)$ and $r\leq e$, then I see that $p^r$ divides the $p^e$ part of $E$, but why can I assume that there are not other components in the product $\mathrm{ord}(a)$ that will not divide into $f$?

(I'm also confused about the logical form of the sufficient condition.  Why is it "IF $p^r$ divides $\mathrm{ord}(a)$, THEN $r\leq e$"?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That last statement is an instance of this fact, which is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic:

> Let $x,y \in \mathbb Z$. Then $x$ divides $y$ iff $v_p(x) \le v_p(y)$ for all primes $p$.

Here, $v_p(x)$ is the exponent of $p$ in the factorization of $x$.

---

The proof given in that book seems too complicated. The proposition follows directly from $\{ k \in \mathbb Z : a^k =1 \} = \operatorname{ord}(a) \mathbb Z$, which is a simple consequence of Euclidean division. This holds for elements of finite order in every group, not just finite abelian ones.

Comment: Your statement about fta led me to realize that I had a quantifier and scope misunderstanding: N&W's statement is: if, $\forall \mbox{ prime } p$, $p^r$ divides $\mathrm{ord}(a)$ $\rightarrow$ $r\leq e$, then $\mathrm{ord}(a)$ divides $E$. What I didn't understand is that the inner conditional has to hold for all prime $p$.  Selecting different prime numbers as $p$, "shifts" them out of the $f$ component role and into the $p^e$ role. If, for any such $p$, $r$ is always less then $e$, no matter what $p^e$ is, then it must be that $\mathrm{ord}(a)$ divides $E$. ...thinking about the other point.